# am trying to make a login with facebook using codeigniter but it shows error

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

my code is

```
    <?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
      require_once 'php-graph-sdk/autoload.php'; 
      use Facebook\Facebook as FB;
     use Facebook\Authentication\AccessToken;
     use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException;
     use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException;
    use Facebook\Helpers\FacebookJavaScriptHelper;
    use Facebook\Helpers\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
   Class Facebook
   {
   private $fb;
  private $helper;

    public function __construct(){
    // Load fb config
    $this->load->config('facebook');
    // Load required libraries and helpers
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    if (!isset($this->fb)){
        $this->fb = new FB([//this line contain error 
            'app_id' => $this->config-
   >item('facebook_app_id'),
            'app_secret'            => $this->config-
     >item('facebook_app_secret'),
            'default_graph_version' => $this->config-
     >item('facebook_graph_version')
        ]);
    }
```

> Type: Error
>   Message: Class 'Facebook\Facebook' not found
>   Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\Code\application\libraries\Facebook.php
>   Line Number: 21

this error is showing on screen.

can anyone please tell me what mistake i have done in my code. Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure if aliasing and autoloading work together ... I would recommend that you try it without aliasing the class.

Comment: no effect i did this

Comment: What PHP SDK version are you using there?

Comment: am using php-graph-sdk-5.1.2

Comment: That sounds like the autoloading mechanism might not be working correctly. Might be that CI’s default autoloader mechanism interferes in some way ...?

Comment: Where does `php-graph-sdk/autoload.php` reside?

Comment: i have downloaded this file from online php-graph-sdk-5.1.2

Comment: I meant in your application. 
Also, best way you could do is to use FB SDK over composer. 
That way you would be sure it is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can match your code with this example.
https://www.codexworld.com/facebook-login-codeigniter/
Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: am doing exactly same but dont know  why i stuck here